# What Should I Do When My App Is Rejected Due to the Reported Error "serviceCatalog:X6" for Payments?

Tags: appgallery-connect

My app submitted for review was rejected by Huawei because the “serviceCatalog:X6” error was discovered for payments. I have checked my test environment by referring to the guide(hyperlink:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-References/quickapp-api-pay): connected to Wi-Fi, used Android and EMUI versions complying with the specifications, and used the environment in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of `serviceCatalog` so it is the same as the app category, and do not use the X6 value for your app.

- Check whether you have called the `GetBuyIntentWithPrice` API. If so, check the value of `serviceCatalog` based on this [material](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/hms-iap-overview-0000001050150067?ha_source=hms1).
  　Note: The `GetBuyIntentWithPrice` API has been brought offline, so this may not be the cause.
- Check your enabled service APIs.

  If you have not called the API, see this [material](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-enable_service#enable-service?ha_source=hms1) to check your enabled services.

  If your app is not a game, **do not enable** Game Service.

[image]

Note: It takes about 15 minutes for your enabling or disabling operations to take effect.